# How I car write Controller function on many to many with relation attributes

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am working on applying many to many relations on table Accident, Car where the relations are as follows:
In the Accident model:

```
public function car()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class,'accident_participateds',
    'reportNo','vehicleId');
}
```

In-car Model

```
public function accidents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Accident::class,'accident_participateds',
        'vehicleId','reportNo')->withPivot(['damageAmount', 'IBAN']);
    }
```

I want to display the data from all 3 Models (Car, Accident,accident_participateds)My question is whether these statements are correct in the controller

```
public function AdminClaims()
    {
        $claim = Accident::with('car')->get();
        $details = Car::with('accidentsr')->get();
        return view('admin.AdminClaims',compact('claim','details'));
        
    }
```

Because when I try to display like this:

```
<tbody>
            @foreach($claim as $claims)
              <tr>
                <td>{{$claims->ReportNumber}}</td>
                @foreach($details as $AP)
                <td>{{$AP->vehicleId}}</td>
                <td>{{$AP->Location}}</td>
                <td>{{$AP->Date}}</td>
                <td>{{$AP->damageAmount}}</td>
                <td>{{$AP->IBAN}}</td>
            @endforeach 
              </tr>
            @endforeach
```

it print only ReportNumber
kindly tell me where I made a mistake?
[image]

Comment: What do you get when you `dd($details)` in the controller.

Comment: some thing like this:  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#469 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Car {#486 ▼
      +timestamps: false
      #table: "cars"
      #fillable: array:5 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to display the details of `Accident`(claim), associated `Car` and data from the **pivot** table.

To do so you can try

```php
public function AdminClaims()
{
    $claims = Car::with('accidents')->get();

    return view('admin.AdminClaims',compact('claims'));
        
}
```

And in view

```php
@foreach($claims as $claim)
    <tr>        
        <td>{{$claim->ReportNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{$claim->vehicleId}}</td>
        <td>{{$claim->Location}}</td>
        <td>{{$claim->Date}}</td>
        <td>{{$claim->pivot->damageAmount}}</td>
        <td>{{$claim->pivot->IBAN}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I try it gives Exiption foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

Comment: Sorry it's a typo, you have named the relations as `car` , conventionally since it returns a collection (`belongsToMany`) it should have been named `cars`. I'm fixing the typo from`$claim->cars` to `$claim->car` in the **@foreach**. Change at your end accordingly and see what you get.

Comment: still display only Report Number

Comment: What does `dd($claim->car, Car::all())` show? Does any of it return empty collection?

Comment: I change  $claims = Car::with('accidents')->get(); and pivot model to display all data Know it's work properly (Thank you )

Comment: @fyafee Have updated the answer accordingly for benefit of future visitors. However I don't know which columns are on which tables, could you check the view part and confirm so that it's not confusing for future visitors